# Oven/Stove or Wiring causing breaker to trip

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker, oven, stove

My Kitchen was delivered some days ago and the persons doing the installation were unable to get the oven/Stove set to work. I am unsure if I have a faulty oven/stove or faulty wiring in the apartment as the apartment was recently renovated and there was no oven installed before. Here is the current behavior:

Oven/Stove set is currently plugged in. However everytime the circuit breaker for the oven/stove is flipped on, the main breaker for the apartment trips and it is lights out for the entire apartment. However, for some very few seconds I can see the clock on the oven/stove turn on and then immediatly off.

I cannot disconnect the oven/stove as it is currently built into the furniture and trying to move it myself would ruin the guarantee.

Has anybody had a similar experience and could give me some input on what could be faulty in such a situation?

Comment: This isn't something that should be asked of the internet (nor do we have enough information to assist). Get a specialist on site.

Comment: If this is a rental "apartment", call the landlord/management immediately. If you own, call back the people who did the renovation and have them double check the wiring. Since there was no oven previously, it's possible that the oven may draw more amps than the circuit is capable of providing, but since it's tripping every time you turn the breaker on, it's obvious there's a wiring issue.

Comment: It isn't "draw more Amps" - an oven when turned on only draws a very little bit of current to run the control panel/clock/etc. Which means it must be "wiring issue".

Comment: The only thing I can see you doing here is looking at the breaker and seeing if it has a "TEST" button on it.  So I'm voting to close because this is a dead-end question. You are blocked from providing enough information to give a viable answer, and you don't need to anyway, since there's a "guarantee".  **Your only recourse is to use the guarantee to force them to come back and fix it. They should have tested it before they left the building**.

Answer (score 3):

If turning on the oven/stove breaker immediately causes the main breaker to trip (without even turning on the oven/stove) something is blatantly miswired.

*What or where is impossible to determine without more detail that you are unable to provide at present.*